# What is a good way to call an API once every `x` amount of time?

Tags: react-native, api

For example `fetch` from the API `X` every 4 hours?

Should this include `caching`, `setTimepout` or something else?

Comment: Depends on your usecase really, there's tons of different solutions i.e. scheduled tasks, cron jobs, background workers, setTimeout.

Comment: Im thinking about an app (news, sports etc) where the API should be called only once a day to fetch the data

Answer (score 3):

I would use react-query which make an amazing job for caching and updating data. You also got an option "refetch interval" that could do exactly what you are looking for. You could also use staletime.
https://react-query.tanstack.com/

If you don't want to use another library you can simply use setTimeOut with useEffect I guess or you could also use schedule task as it as already been said

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I used it. I put it before the API call and the API call will be called only every 4 hours (14400000 milliseconds)

```
useEffect(() => {
const interval = setInterval(() => {
window.location.reload();
}, 14400000);
return () => clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).